# Amazon MP3 Credits, how do I find out if I have them remaining and how many I've got?

Tags: amazon

Amazon has lots of items that claim bonus dollars for Cloud purchases. Take for instance [Fabled City by the The Nightwatchman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EKNYSA).

> Special Offers and Product Promotions
>   Buy a CD, get $1 in Amazon MP3 Credit. Limit one promotional credit per customer. [Here's how](http://www.amazon.com/gp/promotions/details/popup/A2TY5IVGF8LNGO) (restrictions apply)

How do I find out how many of those $1 credits I've accumulated? I know I must have a bunch. It says *Limit one promotional credit per customer.* Does that mean one promotional offer per sale of item that has promotion? Or does it mean one promotional offer for all items that have had this promotion? I've been buying items marked with this text for a year—is it all part of one giant promotion?

Answer (score 2):

When you visit Amazon, you can check the promotional credit by clicking into any MP3 details page ([for example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009MTDD18)).

Under the shopping buttons there is a link that says **Redeem a gift card or promotion code & view balance**.

Your promotional balance and any gift card balance you have will be displayed separately in the resulting window.

Another thing to note: promotional credit expires, so you might not have as much as you think if you have been waiting a year to claim some of this balance.

Comment: Thank you! I had a much more awkward way of checking the gift card balance and promotion code etc balance separately. This is a lot easier.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working in the current UI? I've also marked this question as a duplicate with processes that do still appear to be working.

Comment: Ah, I found it, they've moved it to the slightly less clear "Add gift card or promotion code"